# PySpark: How to convert DataFrame with None to LibSVM format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to convert `DataFrame` to `LibSVM` format.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,None),(0,1),(1,3)],["label","feat"])
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda line: LabeledPoint(line[0], line[1:]))
MLUtils.saveAsLibSVMFile(rdd, path)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Expected `LibSVM` format:

```
1 
0 1:1
1 1:3
```

Comment: Have you found it out in the meanwhile?